# Why two different results to surface areal calculation using Guldin?

Tags: geometry

Guldin's first rule, also known as [Pappus first centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) states that a linear figure creates an area when rotated that is the product of the distance the centroid is moved and the length of the figure.

I should therefore get the same resulting area when I rotate a triangle, as when I rotate the three segments making up the sides of the triangle.
Thus, I must do something wrong when I do not get that. Here are my calculations, provided triangle $ABC$, where $A=(1,1)$, $B=(1,4)$ og $C=(4,3)$.

In procedure 1, I shall calculate the contribution from each segment, then add.
In procedure 2, I shal find the centroid and the perimeter and "directly" calculate the surface area of the volume of rotation.

**Procedure 1**: 
$r_{AB}=1,L_{AB}=3,A_{AB}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{AB}\cdot L_{AB}=6\pi$.
$r_{BC}=\frac{5}{2},L_{BC}=\sqrt{(4-1)^2+(3-4)^2}=\sqrt{10},A_{BC}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{BC}\cdot L_{BC}=5\pi\sqrt{10}$.
$r_{AC}=\frac{5}{2},L_{AC}=\sqrt{(4-1)^2+(3-1)^2}=\sqrt{13},A_{AC}=2\cdot\pi\cdot r_{AC}\cdot L_{AC}=5\pi\sqrt{13}$.

Consequently, the total surface area amounts to $A_1=A_{AB}+A_{BC}+A_{AC}=\pi\left(6+5\sqrt{10}+5\sqrt{13}\right)$.

**Procedure 2:**
Triangle $ABC$ perimeter $L=L_{AB}+L_{BC}+L_{AC}=3+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}$.
Radius of rotation for triangle $ABC$: $r=2$.

Total surface area: $A_2=2\pi r L=4\pi\left(3+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}\right)$.

I expected $A_1=A_2$, but I get $A_1=A_2+\pi\left(-6+\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{13}\right)$.
[image: Triangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two plane figures below are not the same:

[image]

In partricular, their centroids are not in the same spot.

The centroid of the filled-in triangle at right is at (3, 3) as you found, but the centroid of the empty triangle at left is not.

> The centroid of the empty triangle is at the weighted mean of the midpoints of the line segments.
>
> Midpoints: $(1, 2.5), (2.5, 3.5), (2.5, 2)$
>
> Weights: $3, \sqrt{10}, \sqrt{13}$
>
> We only care about the $x$-coordinate of the centroid, though:
>
> $\overline{x} = \frac{1 \cdot 3 + 2.5 \cdot \sqrt{10} + 2.5 \cdot \sqrt{13}}{3 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{13}}$
>
> Multiply numerator and denominator by 2:
>
> $\overline{x} = \frac{6 + 5 \sqrt{10} + 5 \sqrt{13}}{2\left(3 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{13}\right)}$

So the surface area calculated this way is $A_2 = 2 \pi r L = 2 \pi \overline{x} L$, which is

> $A_2 = 2\pi\overline{x}L = 2\pi \frac{6 + 5 \sqrt{10} + 5 \sqrt{13}}{2\left(3 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{13}\right)} \left(3 + \sqrt{10} + \sqrt{13}\right)$
>
> $A_2 = \pi \left(6 + 5 \sqrt{10} + 5 \sqrt{13}\right)$

, as desired.

Comment: Now, I would like to find this _perimeter centroid_ geometrically. I found this [Encycolopedia of Triangle Centers](http://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) but have to work my way through relevant parts before I can settle for **how to construct** the perimeter centroid pointed out _algebraically_ by @Chris

Comment: The above mentioned centroid is the [Spieker Center](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spieker_center) for which I will continue my search of a geometric proof emphasizing the weights, @Chris refer to (side lengths).